# Logical Block number in the "Buffer I/O error"

Tags: lvm, devices

I was trying to determine a bad PV which was causing the LV to report Buffer I/O error and found this interesting behaviour in the "Buffer I/O error" message.

On a Large LV that is mapped to different PVs, I tried to use the "logical block" reported in the error, to match with the dmsetup table to find out which target device it was on. However this method doesn't seem to be reliable.

I used dmsetup to create a device mapper device, with one or a number of holes in it. And the error messages are very interesting and I can't make sense of the pattern.

It seems the "Logical Block" number in the error message depends on the size of the hole and also it's position. Is there a definitive way to locate the actual bad block?

Here are the tests that I did

+++ TEST 1
error block at 8, buffer i/o error at LB 8

```
root@ubuntu:~# dmsetup create test x.tab
root@ubuntu:~# dmsetup table test
0 8 linear 8:16 0
8 1 error 
9 1000 linear 8:16 8
root@ubuntu:~# dd if=/dev/mapper/test of=/dev/null bs=512 count=1000
dd: error reading ‘/dev/mapper/test’: Input/output error
8+0 records in
8+0 records out
4096 bytes (4.1 kB) copied, 0.000977434 s, 4.2 MB/s
root@ubuntu:~# 

Sep  5 17:21:07 ubuntu kernel: [ 1358.811671] bio: create slab <bio-1> at 1
Sep  5 17:21:07 ubuntu kernel: [ 1358.817045] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 8
Sep  5 17:21:07 ubuntu kernel: [ 1358.817192] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 8
Sep  5 17:21:07 ubuntu kernel: [ 1358.817199] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 8
Sep  5 17:21:07 ubuntu kernel: [ 1358.817201] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 8
Sep  5 17:21:07 ubuntu kernel: [ 1358.817203] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 8
Sep  5 17:21:07 ubuntu kernel: [ 1358.817629] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 8
Sep  5 17:21:07 ubuntu kernel: [ 1358.817633] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 8
Sep  5 17:21:07 ubuntu kernel: [ 1358.818649] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 8
Sep  5 17:21:19 ubuntu kernel: [ 1370.324905] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 8
Sep  5 17:21:19 ubuntu kernel: [ 1370.325245] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 8
```

+++ TEST 2
error block at 9, buffer i/o error at LB 4

```
root@ubuntu:~# dmsetup create test x.tab
root@ubuntu:~# dmsetup table test
0 9 linear 8:16 0
9 1 error 
10 1000 linear 8:16 9
root@ubuntu:~# dd if=/dev/mapper/test of=/dev/null bs=512 count=1000
dd: error reading ‘/dev/mapper/test’: Input/output error
8+0 records in
8+0 records out
4096 bytes (4.1 kB) copied, 0.000630946 s, 6.5 MB/s
root@ubuntu:~# 

Sep  5 17:23:28 ubuntu kernel: [ 1499.435904] bio: create slab <bio-1> at 1
Sep  5 17:23:28 ubuntu kernel: [ 1499.440980] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 4
Sep  5 17:23:28 ubuntu kernel: [ 1499.441010] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 4
Sep  5 17:23:28 ubuntu kernel: [ 1499.441037] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 4
Sep  5 17:23:28 ubuntu kernel: [ 1499.441062] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 4
Sep  5 17:23:28 ubuntu kernel: [ 1499.441087] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 4
Sep  5 17:23:28 ubuntu kernel: [ 1499.441314] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 4
Sep  5 17:23:28 ubuntu kernel: [ 1499.441340] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 4
Sep  5 17:23:28 ubuntu kernel: [ 1499.441805] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 4
Sep  5 17:23:53 ubuntu kernel: [ 1524.710414] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 4
Sep  5 17:23:53 ubuntu kernel: [ 1524.710572] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 4
```

+++ TEST 3
error blocks start at 1000 for 10 blocks, buffer i/o error at LB 500

```
root@ubuntu:~# dmsetup create test x.tab
root@ubuntu:~# dmsetup table test
0 1000 linear 8:17 0
1000 10 error 
1010 1000 linear 8:17 1010
root@ubuntu:~# dd if=/dev/mapper/test of=/dev/null bs=512 count=12000
dd: error reading ‘/dev/mapper/test’: Input/output error
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
512000 bytes (512 kB) copied, 0.00278218 s, 184 MB/s
root@ubuntu:~# 

Sep  5 17:37:04 ubuntu kernel: [ 2314.961989] bio: create slab <bio-1> at 1
Sep  5 17:37:12 ubuntu kernel: [ 2322.956596] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 500
Sep  5 17:37:12 ubuntu kernel: [ 2322.956600] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 501
Sep  5 17:37:12 ubuntu kernel: [ 2322.956602] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 502
Sep  5 17:37:12 ubuntu kernel: [ 2322.956603] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 503
Sep  5 17:37:12 ubuntu kernel: [ 2322.956605] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 504
Sep  5 17:37:12 ubuntu kernel: [ 2322.957147] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 500
Sep  5 17:37:12 ubuntu kernel: [ 2322.957149] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 501
Sep  5 17:37:12 ubuntu kernel: [ 2322.957151] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 502
Sep  5 17:37:12 ubuntu kernel: [ 2322.957152] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 503
```

+++ TEST 4
error block at 1000, buffer i/o error at LB 1000

```
root@ubuntu:~# dmsetup create test x.tab
root@ubuntu:~# dmsetup table test
0 1000 linear 8:17 0
1000 1 error 
1001 1000 linear 8:17 1010
root@ubuntu:~# dd if=/dev/mapper/test of=/dev/null bs=512 count=12000
dd: error reading ‘/dev/mapper/test’: Input/output error
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
512000 bytes (512 kB) copied, 0.00379868 s, 135 MB/s
root@ubuntu:~# 

Sep  5 17:38:48 ubuntu kernel: [ 2419.516088] bio: create slab <bio-1> at 1
Sep  5 17:38:54 ubuntu kernel: [ 2425.506135] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 1000
Sep  5 17:38:54 ubuntu kernel: [ 2425.506953] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 1000
```

+++ TEST 5
error blocks start at 1001 for 2 blocks, buffer i/o error at LB 1001

```
root@ubuntu:~# dmsetup create test x.tab
root@ubuntu:~# dmsetup table test
0 1001 linear 8:17 0
1001 2 error 
1003 1000 linear 8:17 1010
root@ubuntu:~# dd if=/dev/mapper/test of=/dev/null bs=512 count=12000
dd: error reading ‘/dev/mapper/test’: Input/output error
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
512000 bytes (512 kB) copied, 0.00362554 s, 141 MB/s
root@ubuntu:~# 

Sep  5 17:42:16 ubuntu kernel: [ 2627.373744] bio: create slab <bio-1> at 1
Sep  5 17:42:24 ubuntu kernel: [ 2635.080482] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 1001
Sep  5 17:42:24 ubuntu kernel: [ 2635.080486] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 1002
Sep  5 17:42:24 ubuntu kernel: [ 2635.081327] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 1001
Sep  5 17:42:24 ubuntu kernel: [ 2635.081329] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 1002
```